# I can't retrieve req.body data with multer

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I can't retrieve the data from req.body using multer. It responds with
[Object: null prototype] {} , if I stringify it as JSON I ofc get {}
My goal is to receive input number in order to add X amount of product to the cart, but I can't seem to get the number.

```
{{# each products }}

  <div class="row">
    {{# each this }} 
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <form action = "/add-to-cart/{{this._id}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
      <div class="img-thumbnail" alt="text-center">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="{{this.imagePath}}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{this.title}}</h3>
        <p class="description">{{this.description}}</p>
        <div class="clearfix">
           <input  type="text" name="Quantity" placeholder="vnt" form="insert-id-of-form" class="float-left">
            <div class="price float-left">{{this.price}}</div>
        <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Užsakyti">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    </form>
    {{/each}}
   
</div>
  {{/each}}
```

This is my code in.js

```
router.post('/add-to-cart/:id',upload.single("Quantity"), function(req, res, next) {
    var productId = req.params.id;
    var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});
    Product.findById(productId, function(err, product) {
      var boxSize = req.session.boxSize;
      const itemQty = req.body;
      console.log(itemQty);
       if (err) {
           return res.redirect('/products');
       }
       else if (cart.boxSizeQty < boxSize && itemQty == null){
        cart.add(product, product.id);
        req.session.cart = cart;
        res.redirect('/products');
        console.log("item qty null")
       }
       else if (cart.boxSizeQty >= boxSize && itemQty > boxSize){
         res.redirect('/products');
         req.flash('error','Dėžutė pilna');
         console.log("more items than size")
       }
       else if (cart.boxSizeQty < boxSize && itemQty > 0){
         console.log("item quantity is more than 0")
         for (var i = 0; i <= itemQty; i++){
          cart.add(product, product.id);
         }
         req.session.cart = cart;
         res.redirect('/products');
       }
       
    });
});
```

This is part of the app.sj

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var userRouter = require('./routes/user');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var multer = require('multer');
var forms = multer();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
require('./config/passport');
// view engine setup
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(forms.array());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({   extended: true }));
app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(validator());
app.use(cookieParser());
```

I've tried this with multer, formidable, bodyparser but it doesn't seem to parse the input number. Very much stuck on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards,

Comment: have you used this in your  app.js `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));`

Comment: Yes, sadly. It's there and I can parse in another function which takes form data and puts it as a new "order" - it works there. But doesn't work here.

Comment: Why you are using ```json``` and ```urlencoded``` middlewares twice? new express supports that and no needs to ```bodyparser``` external package.

Comment: It's a mess as I am trying different libraries as I was very much stuck on this. 
Problem is now fixed though, apparently the view has to be in one form group div. Otherwise form data is not being passed.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting the answer here, if anyone will get in to a similar issue.

Apparently the problem was that for data wasn't being passed though nodejs part was working fine. It's my mistake for not going to developer options on browser and checking form data which was empty.

Once html part is in one  div

```
{{# each products }}
  <div class="row form-group">
    {{# each this }} 
    <form action = "/add-to-cart/{{this._id}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
      <img src="{{this.imagePath}}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
        <h3>{{this.title}}</h3>
        <p class="description">{{this.description}}</p>
           <input  type="number" name="Quantity" placeholder="vnt" class="float-left">
        <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Užsakyti">
  </div>
    </form>
    {{/each}}
   
</div>
  {{/each}}
```

The data is being properly passed from this form.

Then we need to stringify it to JSON like so:

```
 var itemQty = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body.Quantity));
```

And parse it as int like so:

```
 parseInt(itemQty);
```

All is left is to fix the view.

Thanks to anyone who bothered to read.